# How to check if user select all cells or any cells in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

In datagridview key down event i would like to capture if user select all cells or just any cells data.

```
    Private Sub dg_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles dg.KeyDown

            If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.C Then

                If all cells select then
                    ClipboardCopyMode = EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText
                Else
                    ClipboardCopyMode=EnableWithoutHeaderText
                End if
             End If

    End Sub
```

Any help Pls!

Comment: Create a two dimensional array and store each cell value in their separate location. or you can create a custom class like `myValueClass` with some properties like `ColumnIndex`, `RowIndex`, `Header` and `Value` and create a list of that class object. `List<myValueClass>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few DataGridView methods and properties that will help you out here: `SelectedCells.Count`, `SelectedCells.Rows.Count` and the [`SelectedCells.GetColumnCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.getcolumncount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method.

`SelectedCells.Count` is self explanatory.

To get the total number of cells in a DataGridView you can multiply the number of rows and columns, using the `SelectedCells.Rows.Count` property and the `SelectedCells.GetColumnCount` method, passing in the `DataGridViewElementStates.Visible` parameter to ensure hidden columns are not used in the calculation.

What you need to do is determine if the number of selected cells equals the total number of cells in your DataGridView, like this:

```
Private Function AllCellsSelected(dgv As DataGridView) As Boolean
    AllCellsSelected = (DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count = (DataGridView1.RowCount * DataGridView1.Columns.GetColumnCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)))
End Function
```

I recommend you create a boolean flag that indicates if all cells are selected and set this flag in your DataGridView's [`SelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event handler using the `AllCellsSelected` method.  Check the value of this flag in your `KeyDown`.